# Como configurar vhost no windows com o xampp usando uma porta diferente da 80?

Tags: php, windows, xampp, virtualhost

**Alguém sabe como configurar vhost no windows com o xampp usando uma porta diferente da 80?!**

Estou com problemas para configurar o host para implementar uma aplicação em PHP.

Meu arquivo **httpd.conf** já está com estas configurações:

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

ServerName localhost:8080

Listen 8080

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

---

Meu arquivo **httpd-vhosts.conf** já está com estas configurações:

```
<VirtualHost local.projeto.com:*>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto"
    ServerName local.projeto.com
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**E meu arquivo **hosts** (do windows) já está com as seguintes configurações:**

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
::1              localhost

#127.0.0.1       activate.navicat.com

127.0.0.1        local.projeto.com
```

Obs.: A porta 80 no computador já está em uso. Estou conseguindo acessar normalmente localhost:8080/dashboard, o problema está nos hosts personalizados.

Comment: Vá no iniciar, se for windows10, digita **"Monitor de Recursos"** (sem aspas), e veja qual programa esta usando a porta 80, finaliza ele, pronto o apache deverá funcionar, mas NÃO se esqueça que no .conf do apache você deve colocar o `Listen` as portas, leia: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html. Vou fechar os comentários, pq o site aqui não é para resolver problemas técnicos, só ajudei pq imaginei q fosse confusão da porta mesmo. O escopo do site é restrito a problemas programação e não servidores, sugiro no futuro fazer perguntas sobre servidores: https://serverfault.com